# How to sort a map by a specific field in es6 / React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got this map that I'd like to sort by "id" value:

```
{products.map(({ id, headline }) => (
  <Container>
    <Row key={id}>
      <Col>
        <p>id={id}</p>
        <p>headline={headline}</p>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
))}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: What data type is `id`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216/218196)

Comment: if you can do `.map` you can do `.sort`

Comment: Do you know if the `id` of a product is a number or a string?

Comment: The "id" property is a number.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming `id` is a number you can do `products.sort(({id: previousID}, {id: currentID}) => previousID - currentID)`

Like so:

**JavaScript Code:**

```
{products
   .sort(({ id: previousID }, { id: currentID }) => previousID - currentID)
   .map(({ id, headline }) => (
     <Container key={id}>
       <Row>
         <Col>
           <p>id={id}</p>
           <p>headline={headline}</p>
         </Col>
       </Row>
     </Container>
   ))
}
```

Comment: double check the return of sort

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to finish typing it. But I put it in the top part, it sorts them from lowest to hightest, I tested that part.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: @ChrisBrownie55 You have a typo in `.sort(({ id: previousID }, { id: currentID }) => previoudID - currentID)`  (previoudID should be previousID).

Answer (score 9):

You could [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the array before you `map` it:

```
{products.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id).map(({ id, headline }) => (
  <Container>
    <Row key={id}>
      <Col>
        <p>id={id}</p>
        <p>headline={headline}</p>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
))}
```